# Codeigniter: Extract certain value from an array under controller

Tags: codeigniter

Good day!

This is pretty basic to some.

I have this code on my controller:

```
$data["sales_info"] = $this->The_model->get_sales_info(SELECT * FROM sales WHERE sales_id = 123);
```

Then *get_sales_info()* method under *The_model* stores the specific sales information into an array.

Now, I'm doing some debugging, so from the controller, I want to extract from the *$data["sales_info"]* and echo only the value of 'sales_date'.

How am I going to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution for your problem:

Change the model file to :

> The_model.php

```
class The_model extends MY_Model {
    function get_sales_info($sales_id){
        $this->db->select("*.*");
        if(!empty($sales_id)){
            $this->db->where('sales_id', $sales_id);
            $query = $this->db->get('sales');
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            $query = $this->db->get('sales');
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
}
```

and change the controller file to:

> My_controller.php

```
$sales_id = 123;
$sales_info = $this->The_model->get_sales_info($sales_id);
echo $sales_info['sales_date'];exit; //how to get value from object
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Aaand, question.. can I also echo other data using $sales_info['any_column']? =)

Comment: Yes you can get any column from return `get_sales_info` function.

Comment: I not sure why have exit

Answer (score 2):

This code may help you

```
$sales_info = $this->The_model->get_sales_info(SELECT * FROM sales WHERE sales_id = 123);
$data['sales_data'] = $sales_info['sales_date'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('sales', array('sales_id' => 123));
```

It should be like this, you cannot write the sql in to a method as best practice.